# how to update a column using oracle trigger

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER demands 
AFTER INSERT ON demand 
FOR EACH ROW 
 
DECLARE 
   MRPs number; 
BEGIN 
  SET demand.MRP=10;

   dbms_output.put_line('Salary difference: ' || :NEW. PRODUCT_NAME); 
END;
```

I want to set the mrp =value x (which is not same every time for solving the issue we are supposing it to be 10 ) after the row is inserted

Answer (score 0):

Use `:NEW.MRP := 10` in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger (if you use `AFTER INSERT` then the value will already have been inserted and you cannot change it).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER demands 
  BEFORE INSERT ON demand 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  :NEW.MRP := 10;
END; 
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0db329320c01bc86f8d71cf1f241e380)*